# Conflit between Context API and Next js Routing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I was just following along a tutorial for Material UI from udemy, and I set up a Context API in Create React App and didn't pass down props like in the tutorial. Then later I wanted to migrate to Next JS with that Context API and now I am constantly getting errors like the one below:

`Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

`pages\_document.js (57:4) @ Object.ctx.renderPage`

```
  55 | 
  56 |   ctx.renderPage = () =>
> 57 |     originalRenderPage({
     |    ^
  58 |       enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
  59 |     });
```

Here is my _app.js:

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
        />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />

        {/* This is the Context API Consumer */}
        <Navigation>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Navigation>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The `Navigation` component is the Context API Consumer.

Any help is much appreciated as I am really lost!

Thank You. :)

Edit: I am very new to Next.js

Comment: Next.js is black-box for your app and pages, you MUST follow the rules of custom app in Next.js framework. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: @XXLIVE, I tried to create a custom app and do it but It returns the same error :((

Comment: Could you make a `codesandbox` for this?

Comment: @XXLIVE, I solved it! Thanks for the help :))

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-evaluating my webpage files again, I found out that I forgot to change the `to` prop to `href` which was causing the problem. Now all is well..